# Creating Pairs by Group and Keep the Groups ids

Tags: r

Here below an example of what I would like:

From this data frame:

```r
data<-data.frame(id_group=c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C", "C"),id_entity=c(1,2,2,3,4,2,5,1),nb_members=c(2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3))


  id_group id_entity nb_members
        A         1          2
        A         2          2
        B         2          3
        B         3          3
        B         4          3
        C         2          3
        C         5          3
        C         1          3
```

With the following code I manage to obtain the connections by pairs:

```r
m <- crossprod(table(data[-3]))
m[upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <-0
t_data<-subset(as.data.frame.table(m))
t_data <- t_data%>%subset(id_entity.1 != id_entity)

id_entity id_entity.1 Freq
         2           1    2
         3           1    0
         4           1    0
         5           1    1
         1           2    0
         3           2    1
         4           2    1
         5           2    1
         1           3    0
         2           3    0
         4           3    1
         5           3    0
         1           4    0
         2           4    0
         3           4    0
         5           4    0
         1           5    0
         2           5    0
         3           5    0
         4           5    0
```

However, I would like to keep the information about the groups ids in which the connections are made:

```r
id_entity id_entity.1 Freq   id_group
         2           1    2    A,C
         3           1    0    NA
         4           1    0    NA
         5           1    1    C
         1           2    0    NA
         3           2    1    B
         4           2    1    B
         5           2    1    C
         1           3    0    NA
         2           3    0    NA
         4           3    1    B
         5           3    0    NA
         1           4    0    NA
         2           4    0    NA
         3           4    0    NA
         5           4    0    NA
         1           5    0    NA
         2           5    0    NA
         3           5    0    NA
         4           5    0    NA
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this by making a table that mirrors the table used in `crossprod()`, but that has letters where there are non-zero values in the table of frequencies.  Then, you can use information for `id_identity` and `id_identity.1` to find the appropriate columns of the letter table.  You want to past together the intersecting values from those two columns. You can replace the letter values with `NA` when the frequency count is zero.

```r
library(dplyr)
d<-data.frame(id_group=c("A","A","B","B","B","C","C", "C"),id_entity=c(1,2,2,3,4,2,5,1),nb_members=c(2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3))

tab <- table(d[-3])
tab2 <- apply(tab, 2, function(x)ifelse(x == 1, rownames(tab), ""))
m <- crossprod(table(d[-3]))
m[upper.tri(m, diag = TRUE)] <-0
t_data<-as.data.frame.table(m)
t_data <- t_data%>%subset(id_entity.1 != id_entity)

t_data$pairs <- apply(t_data, 1, function(x)paste(intersect(tab2[,x[1]], tab2[,x[2]]), collapse=","))
t_data$pairs <- gsub("^\\,", "", t_data$pairs)
t_data$pairs <- ifelse(t_data$Freq == 0, NA, t_data$pairs)
t_data
#>    id_entity id_entity.1 Freq pairs
#> 2          2           1    2   A,C
#> 3          3           1    0  <NA>
#> 4          4           1    0  <NA>
#> 5          5           1    1     C
#> 6          1           2    0  <NA>
#> 8          3           2    1     B
#> 9          4           2    1     B
#> 10         5           2    1     C
#> 11         1           3    0  <NA>
#> 12         2           3    0  <NA>
#> 14         4           3    1     B
#> 15         5           3    0  <NA>
#> 16         1           4    0  <NA>
#> 17         2           4    0  <NA>
#> 18         3           4    0  <NA>
#> 20         5           4    0  <NA>
#> 21         1           5    0  <NA>
#> 22         2           5    0  <NA>
#> 23         3           5    0  <NA>
#> 24         4           5    0  <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>